# SPRING MVC - Dynamic population of a drop-down upon another drop-down selection

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, dynamic, drop-down-menu

We are using spring-mvc version 2.5 . I am struggling with the concept of loading a second dropdown control based on the selection of the first dropdown. I would really prefer to not have to introduce something like jQuery into the project at this time - if at all possible. I'm pretty sure this was do-able before jQuery.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

First, start off with a single dropdown list which has a list of employee names keyed by employee id's.

Then, upon making a selection from this list - load up and display a second drop down which lists the offices they have keyed by office id's

Then, lastly - make a selection from the second list (offices) and display the submit button

In terms of the jsp code, I run into trouble from the beginning. I am not able to submit the form to the controller when there is a change in the dropdown. The onChange event cannot be used with the  tag. If I use this (below), the value of the selection is not passed to the controller:

```
<select path='employee' onChange="submit();">
    <option value="${selected}" selected>${selected}</option>
        <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="currentEmployee">
            <c:if test="${currentEmployee!= selected}">
                <option            value="${currentEmployee.employeeId}">${currentEmployee.employeeName}</option>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
</select>

</form:form>
```

I have no idea how to pass the selection to the controller. Obviously, need to know the selection so I can load up the second drop down with the corresponding data of the selected employee.

I've tried the initBinder method:

```
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] {"employees"});
    Employee employee = (Employee)binder.getTarget();
```

but the employee object is not found.

The onSubmit method doesn't pick up the value either:

```
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws ServletException 
{
    String selectedEmployee = ((Employee) command).getName();
    logger.info("The Selected Employee is: " + selectedEmployee );
```

This doesn't pick up the selected employee either. I am very new to Spring and I suspect that I am way off base with doing this sort of dynamic loading. Is it possible to do this with spring (withut jQuery)? Once I can dynamically load off of drop down selections, I think I can work through the rest.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to do it without all kind of Ajax like Java Script, or just without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML select tag does not have a `path` attribute. It has a `name` attribute. The Spring `form:select` has a `path` attribute.

Use `<form:select ...>` and not just `<select ...>`.